# how I can find the coordinate of three dimensional drawing?

Tags: tikz-pgf

coordinates of point in three dimensional drawing is hard to find, how it  is possible to find them like this example
http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/3d-cone/

Comment: I don't understand this question, at all.

Comment: It is indeed really hard, if not impossible. The example you gave is generated from another language, a language that treats 3D-calculation like friends.

Comment: One comment in that code reads `The following code is generated by Sketch. I have edited it a bit to make it easier to read.`

Comment: In his specific example, the polygon seems to be regular, so the points are evenly spaced around a circle. For the octagon depicted, it could e.g. be `n*360/8` (for `n` from 0 to 7). Using trigonometry gives e.g. `({r*cos(angle)}, {r*sin(angle)}, h)` where `r` is the radius and `h` is the height of the polygon. If you want it translated, or even worse, rotated, then things are going to become more difficult.

Comment: So you should probably ask a question on [math stackexchange](http://math.stackexchange.com/)? Something like _"How to find the coordinates of the vertices of a truncated pyramid with a regular n-gon base?"_

Comment: In the link you posted, math involves  more than drawing. Also, you optimize the code with polar coordinates and foreach loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It *is* very difficult, but this may help you:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{3d}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
   \begin{scope}[canvas is xz plane at y=5]
      \draw[red] (0,0) grid (5,5);
   \end{scope}

   \begin{scope}[canvas is xz plane at y=0]
      \draw[blue] (0,0) grid (5,5);
   \end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

It draws a blue and a red grid on the two "floors" to help you read the coordinates. You can easily adapt this for the xy or the yz plane. However, you will need to know the position of the planes.

[image]